# LAN Driver Interruptions

Tags: driver, cpu, lan

I need to know how the computer handles Local Area Network Input and Output Processor interruptions. I have been looking for a while but can't seem to find anything. Came across some RJ-45 port information but not much of what I specifically need. If someone has some information on how the CPU interrupts a process to call the pointer and therefore the driver, plus how this process works it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the driver for the LAN card configured the card to issue an interrupt when the receive buffer gets close to full or the send buffer gets close to empty. Typically, these buffers live in system memory and the network hardware uses DMA to pull transmitted packets and store received packets in system memory.

When the interrupt triggers, some process on some core is typically interrupted and the network code begins executing. If it's a send interrupt and there are more packets to send, more packets are attached to the send buffer. If it's a receive interrupt, typically more packet buffers are attached to the receive buffer. The driver typically arranges for a "bottom half" to be dispatched to handle whatever other work needs to be done (such as processing the received packets) and the the interrupts completes.

There's a ton of possible variation based upon many factors, but this is the basic idea.